# Do I need a transit visa in the US if I have a J-1 visa?

Tags: visas, usa, transit, paperwork, j1-visas

Do I require a US transit visa if I have a valid, unexpired J1 visa when I enter US?

For example, let's say I catch a flight from Delhi, India to New York City. I would take a day in NYC for sightseeing or visiting relatives, and the next day, I would fly to Florida from NYC.

In this case, do I need a US transit visa, other than the regular J1 visa?

Comment: Transit means traveling through the US to reach another country.  The trip you describe does not meet that definition.  Your trip to the US must comply with the conditions of your J-1 visa, but there's nothing forbidding you from an incidental visit to any place in the US while you are en route to your destination.

Answer (score 2):

If you can live in the US (which you can on a J-1 visa) you can transit there.

As long as you're still an exchange student (i.e. if your DS-2019 is unexpired), you can enter the US on your J-1 visa.

That said, you're staying in the US, so this is not transit